# Ranorex Automation Tool Usage

Tags: automation

I may need to work with Ranorex Automation tool for automating
NW.js Desktop based web technologies implemented
can anyone please share your work experiences with this tool?
Thanks,
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason why you would want to use Ranorex for this work.
Have you considered Selenium which is free and should work great with NW.js